# Ubuntu doesn't see directories which definitely exist

Tags: ubuntu-18.04

When I typed `/home/ant/documents/` into the Terminal, I got the following message:

```
bash:/home/ant/documents: no such file or directory
```

The directory definitely exists.

Answer (score 5):

Most likely you are looking for `/home/ant/Documents/` (mind the capital `D`) - in Linux file and directory names are case sensitive.

In addition to that, just typing `/home/ant/Documents/` makes no sense ... did you mean `cd /home/ant/Documents/` ?

Answer (score 0):

Check if your directory is hidden. Hidden files and directories begin with a . in a directory example: `.directory`
So do one thing open terminal, type `ls -al` .The  `-a` shows hidden file as well as directories.